# How to respect carriage return (CR) from List<int> into String in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert List into String and show it in Text widget in flutter but it's not working as expected. Snippet below:

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

List<int> val = [49, 46, 13, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111];
final decoded = utf8.decode(val);


....

Container(
    child: Text(decoded)
)
```

The text is showing:

> 1. hello

it should be:

> 1.
> hello

Why it does not respect 13 (equivalent to carriage return)?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use `LineSplitter` to split the `String` into a list of lines and then combine the lines again using a `StringBuffer`:

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8, LineSplitter;

void main() {
  final val = [49, 46, 13, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111];
  final lines = const LineSplitter().convert(utf8.decode(val));
  print(lines); // [1., hello]

  final message = lines
      .fold<StringBuffer>(
          StringBuffer(), (buffer, line) => buffer..writeln(line))
      .toString();
  print(message);
  // 1.
  // hello
}
```

This will ensure you are using the running platform supported line endings.

If it works it can be shorten down to:

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8, LineSplitter;

void main() {
  List<int> val = [49, 46, 13, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111];

  final decoded = utf8.decode(val);
  print(decoded);

  final fixed = fixNewLines(decoded);
  print(fixed);
}

String fixNewLines(String text) => const LineSplitter()
    .convert(text)
    .fold<StringBuffer>(StringBuffer(), (buffer, line) => buffer..writeln(line))
    .toString();
```

Comment: Thank you. this works. i tried using buffer..write() instead of writeln and it didn't work anymore. So this leads me to believe that, what this does is, it's splitting the string then concatenating them again with \n at the end of each strings when using writeLn. so the 3rd string in list (13) will become (\r\n). that is why it works. 

so i've tried utf8.decode(val).split('\r').join('\n') and it also worked fine. Do you think it's better to use this solution compared to LineSplitter?

Comment: Well, it is up to you.` LineSplitter` will take any `\n` and/or `\r` and use it for splitting. So this solution is good if you have some mixed input. The split solution is great if you know for sure that your strings will always only contain `\r`.

Comment: yes you are right. your solution is more robust. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, Flutter looks for LF for line break and ignore CR. If you replace 13 (CR) by 10 (LF) it will works.

I don't know if this is a bug or it is platform dependent (tested on Android).

Comment: Android is Linux-based.  There should be no expectation on POSIX/POSIX-like systems to treat CR as a line terminator.

Comment: yes this is true. I've tried using 10 and it worked fine. also tried 13 10 (CRLF) and it's also working fine. CR is not treated as a newline in flutter Text widget. So i guess the solution is, always add LF after CR as what i've commented on the first answer. Thanks